# Query Problem...!

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, lightning-aura-components, visualforce-component

I want to execute a query by comparing two fields of the different object in WHERE clause, but I am not able to use a field on the left-hand side of a condition in a WHERE clause:

```
Public with sharing class RecipeUtility {
       public Id recId{get;set;}
       public RecipeUtility(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        recId = controller.getRecord().Id;
        }


    Public static void createReview(List<Master_Material__c> listRecipes) {

       List<Line_Item1__c> Con = new List<Line_Item1__c>();
        List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
        List<Orderes__c> Ord = new List<Orderes__c>();
          Line_Item1__c Ins = new Line_Item1__c();
        List<Orderes__c> Ord1 = new List<Orderes__c>();

       for(Master_Material__c a: listRecipes){

          acc = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE id = :a.Account__c];
           if(acc.size()>0){
            Ord1 = [SELECT Id,Name,Vendor_Name__c FROM Orderes__c WHERE Vendor_Name__c = :acc[0].Name];
            a.Account__c.adderror(Ord1[0].Name);
               }
       }


   }
}
```

Comment: Please be more precise about what you're trying to do.

Comment: In a where clause you can only compare a field with a value - see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm.

Comment: I don't see in your example where you are even doing what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce doesn't allow to use object fields in right side of where clause.

For instance, `select id from account where name = phone` is an invalid Soql.